# add_menu_page for multiple users in wp theme'

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm unable to understand that how can we use `add_menu_page` for multiple roles.By declaring the same `add_menu_page` for two roles means one over-rides the other, and it will show only for the last declared one.
thnx in advance!!!

```
        function addMenu() {
    add_menu_page("Jobify Menu", "Jobify_user", "Administrator", "jobifyMenu",'displaypage', null, 3);
    add_menu_page("Jobify Menu1", "Jobify_job", "Administrator", "jobifyMenu",'displaypage', null, 3); 
}
```

Comment: `add_menu_page()` is **not** asking for a role but for a capability. Use that, because you don't know anyway which role has a specific capability.

Comment: then what should i do,if i want to add two menus in my wp theme?